# Calculate $\int \int_B f(x,y) dxdy$

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Calculate $\int \int_B f(x,y) dxdy$ where $B$ is the area enclosed by
\begin{align*}
&y=-1\\
&x=\sin(\pi y)\\
&y=(x+1)^3
\end{align*}
and $f(x,y)=xy^2$.

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
\int \int_B f(x,y) dxdy=\int_{-1}^{(x+1)^3} \int_{-2}^0 xy^2 dxdy=\int_{-1}^{(x+1)^3} -2y^2 dy  = \frac{-2}{3}((x+1)^9+1)
\end{align*}

Is that OK? Or schould I express $x=\sqrt[3]{y}-1$ and do $\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-2}^{\sqrt[3]{y}-1} xy^2 dx dy$? But then I get complex results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer integral should never carry functions as its bounds (only numbers are allowed in this scope). You should write
$$
\iint_B f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{-1}^1\int_{\sqrt[3]{y}-1}^{\sin\pi y}xy^2dxdy
$$

Comment: OK thanks. But how did you know that $\int_{\sqrt[3]{y}-1}^{\sin \pi y}$ must be this way?

Comment: A visualization helps a lot. I added such a thing for more clarity in https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j4wqiw8vh4.

Comment: thanks, I see it now.